# Как сохранить Uri в базу данных

Tags: java, android

Я загружаю фото из галлереи таким способом

```
mDownloadPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

Затем

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO){
        updatePhoto();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "r", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            setImageBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
        }
    }
}

private void setImageBitmapFromUri(Uri uri){
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
        ImageView.ScaleType scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER;
        mPhotoCard.setScaleType(scaleType);
        mPhotoCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mCard.setPhotoName(uri.getScheme());
        mCardLab.updateCard(mCard);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), uri.getScheme(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Как поместить Uri в базу данных чтобы при последующем запуске, программа загружала картинку уже автоматически, извлекая uri из базы данных

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Не знаете, как создать базу данных, как в БД поместить запись, как прочитать из БД, как определить загружать из БД или с галереи, другое? Что уже сделали сами, что не получается. В текущем виде ваш вопрос слишком общий и требует решения нескольких проблем, в то время как в вопросе должна быть только одна проблема. Код в вопросе никак не относится к проблеме (нет никаких попыток работы с БД)

Comment: База данных готова и я умею с ней работать, я не знаю как преобразовать Uri в запись чтобы поместить в базу данных, а потом как из записи создать Uri

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записать `Uri` в базу данных, его необходимо преобразовать в строку, а строку сохранить в БД.

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
stringUri = uri.toString();
```

Для обратного преобразования, получаете из БД строку и преобразуете ее в `Uri`:

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
```

Comment: Я сделал точно так как вы сказали. Если что, я получаю Uri на фотку из галлереи. Но при попытке загрузить фото по Uri срабатывает блок catch, вот этими строками я пытаюсь получить фото

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
        mPhotoCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap);